# My method.add(int) does not add the user input into my array

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

I am trying to create an Array that asks the user for it's length, and then asks the user to input many single words into the array one at a time. However my code sentences.add(s); does not add my "S" variable into my ArrayList called sentences.Could you please take a look at my code to see what I am doing incorrectly. *EDIT* When running, after entering the length of the array the program the program asks me to enter a word but immediately 
prints on the line below it with two brackets [] and stops the program there. If anyone know why this was happing I would appreciate it so much!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UsingWords
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an array length ");
        int lengthArray = scan.nextInt();

        ArrayList<String[]> sentences = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        for (int i=0; i <= lengthArray; i++); { 
            System.out.println("Please enter a word: "); 
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            sentences.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sentences));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does line `sentences.add(s)` not throw an exception?

Comment: It comes up with with this error File: /Users/ashtonmeade/Downloads/UsingWords.java  [line: 17]
Error: /Users/ashtonmeade/Downloads/UsingWords.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.lang.String)
location: class java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]>

Comment: This doesn't compile. You cannot add a ``String`` to a data structure that contains ``String[]`` elements.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, so...

Comment: Btw, that means you're not even using a decent development environment. What are you using, notepad?

Comment: @LppEdd I am using Dr.Java, I'm very new to java.

Comment: @Johnburks I suggest going with IntelliJ Community. Inspections will give you tons of help and insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not work because you declared an ArrayList of String[] and you try to add a String into it.

I.E. `sentences` should be a of `ArrayList<String>` type.

Comment: change `ArrayList<String[]>` to `ArrayList<String>` This was meant for @johnburks

Comment: ohhh so just remove the []? Would that be a simple fix.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I am new to java and this site and usually people are so mean.

Comment: @Johnburks When you add the brackets it thinks your creating an Arraylist of string l̶i̶s̶t̶s̶ arrays

Comment: @Matt rather an Arraylist of string arrays. That's a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are using arrays in combination with `ArrayList`.
I suspect you want something like this:

```
//remove the "[]" here
ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i <= lengthArray; i++); { 
  System.out.println("Please enter a word: "); 
  String s = scan.nextLine();
  sentences.add(s);
}
//..and the Arrays.toString here
System.out.println(sentences);
```

Comment: maybe even `List<String> sentences = ...`

Comment: @JackFlamp correct, but I didn't want to add more confusion to this topic.